# How to use OR condition with TestNG assertions

Tags: java, testing, junit, testng, assertions

Is there a way to do assertions with `OR`  with TestNG?

This is what I am trying to find:

```
assertEquals(expected, value1 || value2); // Can be any number of values.
```

Comment: I don't know if TestNG has support for [Hamcrest](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/), but it would be pretty easy to do with Hamcrest's machers. Something like `assertThat(expected, either(equalTo(value1)).or(equalTo(value2)))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a very simple wrapper around the TestNG code:

```
private void assertContains(Object actual, Object ... expected) {
    assertTrue(Arrays.asList(expected).contains(actual));
}
```

I briefly looked through the [TestNG source code](https://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/branches/alex20080113/src/main/org/testng/Assert.java) and didn't see any methods similar to the method above, but I am not very familiar with the TestNG patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a workaround with boolean assertions:

```
if(condition1 || condition2){
   Assert.assertTrue(true)
} else {
   Assert.fail("Your Explanation here")
}
```